# Convert strings in a text file (already in tuple format) to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, file, tuples, converters

I have a txt file, "first.txt," that looks like this:

```
(abc, bcd)

(cde, sos)

(feg, rof)

etc.
```

I also have another list (let's call this "second") that looks like this, already in tuple format (A tuple consisting of two strings):

```
('sos','ten')

('rof','bcd')

etc.
```

I want to compare these two lists and get the difference between them. To do so, I need "first.txt" to be converted to the same tuple format as my list, "second."

I tried doing some list comprehension and then converting the string to a tuple and splitting on "\n", but that just gives ('(abc, bcd)', ''), whereas I want a tuple consisting of two strings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if none of your text element conatin `(`, `)`, or `,`, you can use regular string function to "parse" the tuple, like this:

```py
content = """\
(abc, bcd)
(cde, sos)
(feg, rof)
"""

result = [tuple(line.strip('()').split(",")) for line in content.splitlines()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('abc', ' bcd'), ('cde', ' sos'), ('feg', ' rof')]
```

Comment: What about if you're reading the contents from a text file? In this case, wouldn't you need to save the output in the contents format (I notice a "\" there?)?

Also, I'd want it in exactly the same format as the second block, so "\n" between tuples, not ",". I'd imagine the split could then be "\n".

Comment: you can use `for t in result:` and write `str(t)` to the output file. should I edit the answer to override first.txt?

Comment: Oh I'm asking more specifically about if first.txt is a file that has the format I put in the initial block (so getting "content" variable from a text file in the first place). That would be different than a commented list that is "content" right?

Comment: it should be the same. I tried imitating it. you can get the same content by `content = open('first.txt').read()`

Answer (score 0):

I know `eval()` is evil, but you can try this:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> with open('second.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         lst.append(eval(line, {}, {}))
...         
>>> lst
[('sos', 'ten'), ('rof', 'bcd')]
```

Your `first.txt` is not really in a `tuple` of `str` format.